Any interesting lattice properties with alloys where $m_2=2 m_1$?
I was creating a homework assignment for some easy heat capacity problems and I found that the rounded molar masses of some metallic elements are nice multiples.
For instance, looking at some rounded molar masses and the actual ratios:
$$Titanium,~48 \frac{g}{mole},~1$$
$$Molybdenum,~96 \frac{g}{mole},~2.005$$
$$Neodymium,~144 \frac{g}{mole},~3.01$$
$$Iridium,~192 \frac{g}{mole},~4.02$$
So I was wondering if there would be any interesting vibrational modes in the lattices of materials where one of the atoms had close to twice the mass of the other.  And if so, do those modes give the alloys any interesting physical properties?  Specifically, a property that wouldn't be present when something where the masses didn't have any particularly nice relationship to one another.

An interesting question to ponder. I would say it makes it more likely that some phonon modes are degenerate, but that is already the case for many elemental solids.
